# How to express that I got fined for 50 dollars and lost 5 points from my driving licence?

Tags: expressions

Is there a simple sentence that can express the situation that I got a fine ticket for 50 dollars and lost 5 points from my driving licence? Or, how to express the idea 'I was fined for 50 dollars' and 'I lost 5 points from my driving licence'

There is a word endorse , Can I say 'I have my licence endorsed with five penalty points and also got a fine tick of 50 dollars.'

Comment: Endorse means either to "give support to in a public way" or to put your signature on something [for various reasons](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/endorse).

Comment: @ColleenV: [The courts can fine you and ‘endorse’ your driving record with penalty points if you’re convicted of a motoring offence,](https://www.gov.uk/penalty-points-endorsements/overview) in the UK . It's perfectly normal to say *My licence was endorsed [with X points],* regardless of how a dictionary might define the "standard" meaning of the word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers interesting - in the US, you would say they're recorded on your license.

Comment: @ColleenV: I didn't realise until I saw your comment, but as soon as I read it I guessed this would probably be a "UK-specific" usage (well - dunno about Aussies, Canucks, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, in the US, in most states, points are *added* not lost after you commit a violation.

> Accumulating points on your driving record is costly. Your insurance premiums will go up, and after a specific number of points, your license can be suspended or revoked; to get your license reinstated you will pay hundreds of dollars in fines and fees. ([Source.](http://www.dmv.org/point-system.php))

So, in simple terms, you could say

> I got a 50 dollar (traffic) ticket and 5 points on my (driving) record.

Comment: I'd say it that way, too, but I'd probably write it differently: either with a hyphen in between "50" and "dollar" – _I got a 50-dollar ticket..._ – or else with a dollar sign – _I got a $50 ticket..._ I'd probably spell out [_five_](http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/questions-and-quandaries/formatting/when-do-i-spell-out-numbers), too, but that's a matter of style.